# new react-native (0.70.1 ) init can't build iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I made a new project with react-native init then ran into terminal yarn iOS and I got a build error:

> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
> CompileC /Users/Mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-aoijdzoxvbwwndbylmokvtqowgiu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Codegen.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.o
> /Users/Mac/doc/code1/app/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm
> normal x86_64 objective-c++
> com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (1 failure)

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? I am getting the same issue with 0.70.4

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have firstly installed all the necessary dependencies like homebrew and watchman. Also ensuer you have a ruby installed by running the command

```
ruby --version
```

If all is properly installed, you might try installing a specific version of react native

```
 npx react-native init MyProjectName --version 0.69
```